# Magento 2: How to get registered customer IP

Tags: magento2, customer, security

Anyone know **how to determine registered customers IP**? I have some spam registrations, so I have to block some IPs. If it's not available from M2 backend then by database table or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)To get the customer Ip, we should try with `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress`.

For example:
`vendor/magento/module-review/Model/ResourceModel/Rating/Option.php`

```
...
$data['remote_ip'] = $this->_remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
$data['remote_ip_long'] = $this->_remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress(true);
$data['customer_id'] = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
...
```

- `vendor/magento/module-developer/Helper/Data.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-send-friend/Model/SendFriend.php`

2)We can use `.htaccess` to check the ip.

```
order allow,deny 
deny from 123.123.* 
allow from all
```